# Looping through an ObservableCollection to expand nested items dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a `default` folder function on my treeview based file explorer, this makes the system open folders based on the default path `on load`.

As you know you need to use the `IsExpanded` function to open the `treeviewitem`.

My issue is I don't know how to make it automatically go through each folder and expand until it reaches the default path (Which can be set to anything).

**Here is the very poor code** (that isn't dynamic and smells bad):
[image: bad code for the expander]

**Running the code above achieves** (in run-time):

[image: Folder view]

**To clarify the question:** this code smells and isn't dynamic is there something simpler then looping through each folder to find a folder, expanding it, and going inside of that folder and doing the same thing?

***I'm happy to add anything to this question that can help, and respond to anyone willing to help.***

Thank you all!

Comment: My advice is to check this guy up, he made a video about treeview [AngelSix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OwyNiLPDNw) .

Comment: @J.Memisevic That's actually how this `TreeView` got started, now I just need to automatically open the folders to a path on load. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Recursive Method:

```
private void Expand(DirectoryItemViewModel dvm)
{
     dvm.IsExpanded = true;
     foreach(DirectoryItemViewModel item in dvm.Children)
         Expand(item);
}
```

use it Like:

```
foreach(DirectoryItemViewModel item in Items)
     Expand(Item);
```

Comment: How could this be used in relation to the `this.Items = new ObservableCollection<DirectoryItemViewModel>(children.Select(drive => new DirectoryItemViewModel(drive.FullPath, DirectoryItemType.Drive)));` variable?

Comment: Yeah that works perfect to expand every folder in my treeview so that's much better, but how will this just open say `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe`

Comment: Well it loops through only the childrens of the given `DirectoryItemViewModel`, so just call Expand for the single DirectoryItemViewModel with path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe`

Comment: @CHunter sorry I was not behind my pc, if you have any problems we can continue in chat.